# WPF or ASP.NET for creating a simple multiple access application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, sqlite

I have read some related articles but didn't find a perfectly fitting answer to my questions.

I need to create a simple application to perform basic accountancy related operations. The requirement is such that multiple users (in my case up to 5 people) in the same LAN need to be able to work on the same database from their machines. As the application is going to be simple (basic add/subtract operations and storing the results in the database) I wonder whether I need to use ASP.NET or I can use WPF implementing basic communication interface (WCF seems to be a good helper) as I was working mostly with WPF and have only little experience with ASP.NET. To keep simple again, I decided to use SQLite instead of RDMS (like MS SQL Server or MySQL). I read [here](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) that it is better to use client/server DB for my purpose but I believe that the scale of my project is so small that eventual latencies will not bother me. What I need to know is whether it is wise to use WPF with SQLite database as a shared network resource and accessed by other users or it is better to dive into ASP.NET for this reason.

**To sum up my requirements:**

1. The application is very simple in terms of performed tasks (only basic accountancy related operations),
2. Simple database (SQLite is my choise),
3. Multiple access but only for few people (up to 3 or 5 people),
4. The users will be in the same network,
5. I do not bother about eventual latencies

**My doubts are:**

1. In my case - will it be wise to use SQLite concurrency embedded mechanism if the traffic is very small (only few people)? In the SQLite docs it is stated that basic concurrency is handled in terms of multiple reading access and only single write access at the same time. However I have never used concurrency in SQL so I would need an opinion of somebody more experienced in this topic,
2. Is it better to learn more ASP.NET to create a basic client/server app (I would prefer SQLite as DB again) than implementing WPF with some network related stuff like accessing the shared SQLite file or using WCF to achieve the same? I mean, isn't it complicating everything too much by prefering WPF over ASP.NET? If the application was supposed to be big, scalable etc. I would definitely stick to ASP.NET but in the case of simplicity of the project and simplicity of creating WPF application using C# and XAML I doubt which technology to use in my particular situation to keep simple in the terms of development.

If there is a better solution than the stated above, please mention it (I would prefer to stick with C# but I am open to other suggestions).

Answer (score 2):

The choice of ASP.Net or WPF is entirely down to you. I would recommend that you look at the UseCase Scenarios. In this instance, you are looking at five people needing to use it, so would you then need to create an installer for it to be easily installed on a users machine or would you pass round a USB stick?

Or, would you have it on a web browser and then its only one location and all they need is a URL and then you need to consider authentication.

So, the answer is based on the best scenario that fits your requirements.

Another thing to consider is write it so it doesnt really care what platform its on by using multiple tiers such as having your Business Application Logic, Data Access Layer and then you can have your presentation layers in WPF and ASP.Net

The world as they say is your oyster.

In terms of which database to use, I would use one that held in a central location accessible on the LAN easily so go for something like SQL Express which is FREE and probably much easier to get to grips with.

Comment: I would give them installer (more precisely, I would copy an exe file on their machines). I thought about using SQLite library built-in methods and create queries by myself or using ADO.NET (not sure yet). WPF is easier for my to use but the question is whether to put the effort to create a solid ASP.NET MVC architecture or stick with simple RAD development with WPF. The problem with DB is as such that I may not be able to install SQL server without admin priviliges- that's why I prefer SQLite solution. Anyway, thank you for the answer!

Comment: Based on that, then you need to think about any dll files that will be with the application, and what will you do when you scale it?  It you work in Layers you will have additional dll files and then if you miss one on an update or an install then you will be banging your head asking why it doesnt work on one machine when it works on four others... then go, bugger, im missing a dll.  But, again if you work in layers, you can easily take it from WPF to MVC, and it would just be your presentation layer that changes